# how to automatically increase letter by one to get the next letter in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I need to do in Excel an automatic formula to increase characters alphabetically in each cell of a column:

```
ABCDEFAA
```

...

```
ABCDEFAZ
ABCDEFBA
...
ABCDEFBZ
ABCDEFCA
```

I have the following formula, but can not add more characters:
=IF(RIGHT($A1, 1)="Z", CHAR(CODE(LEFT(A1, 1))+1),LEFT(A1,1))&CHAR(65+MODE(CODE(RIGHT(A1,1))+1-65,26))

How can I update it?

Answer (score 1):

Using `INT` and `MOD` functions, we can update the letter code in the desired manner.  Examine the pattern of the different formulas for the different positions (and recall that `CODE` returns the character code for the **first** character in any string):

Starting from the last letter:

```
CHAR(MOD(CODE(RIGHT(A$1,1))-65+ROW()-1,26)+65)
```

Next to last letter:

```
CHAR(MOD(CODE(RIGHT(A$1,2))-65+INT((ROW()-1)/26),26)+65)
```

3rd from last letter

```
CHAR(MOD(CODE(RIGHT(A$1,3))-65+INT((ROW()-1)/26^2),26)+65)
```

etc.

So, if you need to update the last three letters, you could put together a formula like:

```
= LEFT($A$1,5)&
CHAR(MOD(CODE(RIGHT(A$1,3))-65+INT((ROW()-1)/26^2),26)+65)&
CHAR(MOD(CODE(RIGHT(A$1,2))-65+INT((ROW()-1)/26),26)+65)&
CHAR(MOD(CODE(RIGHT(A$1,1))-65+ROW()-1,26)+65)
```

**NOTE** If you have Excel O365 with the `TEXTJOIN` function, you could use the simpler formula:

```
=LEFT($A$1,5) &TEXTJOIN(,,CHAR(MOD(CODE(RIGHT($A$1,{3,2,1}))-65+INT((ROW()-1)/26^{2,1,0}),26)+65))
```

You could use this variation to include all of the letters in your intial string:

```
=TEXTJOIN(,,CHAR(MOD(CODE(RIGHT($A$1,(9-ROW(INDEX($A:$A,LEN($A$1)):INDEX($A:$A,1)))))-65+INT((ROW()-1)/26^(8-ROW(INDEX($A:$A,LEN($A$1)):INDEX($A:$A,1)))),26)+65))
```

If you have the `SEQUENCE` function, you can shorten it a bit:

```
    =TEXTJOIN(,,CHAR(MOD(CODE(RIGHT($A$1,SEQUENCE(LEN($A$1),,LEN($A$1),-1)))-65+INT((ROW()-1)/26^SEQUENCE(LEN($A$1),,LEN($A$1)-1,-1)),26)+65))
```

Of course, if you involve more than six (6) letters, you will generate more variations than can fit in a single column, so you'd have to develop a multicolumn variation of the formula.

---

[image]

Comment: Oh yeah... perfectly... but I also updated my formula and it's working. Now I have two solutions. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following User Defined Function:

```
Public Function NextLetr(s As String) As String
    Dim i As Long, L As Long, arrL, arrN

    L = Len(s)

    If L = 1 Then
        NextLetr = Chr(Asc(s) + 1)
        If NextLetr = "[" Then
            NextLetr = "AA"
        End If
        Exit Function
    End If

    ReDim arrL(1 To L) As String
    ReDim arrN(1 To L) As Long

    For i = L To 1 Step -1
        arrL(i) = Mid(s, i, 1)
        arrN(i) = Asc(arrL(i))
    Next i
    For i = L To 1 Step -1
        arrN(i) = arrN(i) + 1
        If i = 1 Then Exit For
        If arrN(i) < 91 Then Exit For
        arrN(i) = 65
    Next i

    For i = 1 To L
        arrL(i) = Chr(arrN(i))
    Next i

    NextLetr = Join(arrL, "")
    If Left(NextLetr, 1) = "[" Then
        NextLetr = "AA" & Mid(NextLetr, 2)
    End If
End Function
```

It will take an arbitrary string of capital letters and "bump" it by one:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. But I was asking about the formula in the cell. I don't know how to even work with this code that you typed for me....:(

Comment: I updated my formula, but now it updates only the last letter, while I need to update two last letters alphabetically:
=IF(RIGHT($A1, 1)="ZZ", CHAR(CODE(LEFT(A1, 7))+1),LEFT(A1,7))&CHAR(65+MODE(CODE(RIGHT(A1,1))+1-65,26))